# MediaWiki 1.25 - show content for logged out users only

Tags: php, mediawiki

In my MediaWiki skin (Vector) I want to only show some content for logged out users. In the past I would do this with something like:

```
<?php if( $wgUser->isAnon() ) { ?>
  <p>My content</p>
<?php } ?>
```

However, it appears that in MediaWiki 1.25 the $wgUser global has been deprecated. Given that, what is the best way now to show content if the user is logged out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not edit the Vector skin, it makes upgrading more and more difficult. Maybe you should fork the skin, or using an extension to add your code to the output.

If you still want to do that, it depends on, where you want to add the content. If you want to add it somewhere in VectorTemplate, you could use the data array:

```
<?php if( $this->data['loggedin'] ) { ?>
  <p>My content</p>
<?php } ?>
```

If you're somewhere where you can access an instance of IContextSource, you can use:

```
<?php if( $this->getUser()->isLoggedIn() ) { ?>
  <p>My content</p>
<?php } ?>
```